# How can we simplify this sum over sets expression?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation, arithmetic

I am counting some structures with specific properties. I would like to simplify the counting expression in order to have a more easily evaluable function:

$\vcenter{\hbox{$\sum\limits_{U\in2^{2^W\backslash\{\emptyset\}}\backslash\{\emptyset\}}$}}\left(\left|\left\{(S_A)_{A\in U}~\middle|~S_A\subseteq W\backslash A\land\forall w\in W\backslash(\bigcup U):w\in\vcenter{\hbox{$\bigcup\limits_{A\in U}$}}S_{A}\right\}\right|\right)\\
=\vcenter{\hbox{$\sum\limits_{U\in2^{2^W\backslash\{\emptyset\}}\backslash\{\emptyset\}}$}}\left(2^{\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$\sum\limits_{A\in U}$}}\left(n-|A|\right)\right)}-\left|\left\{(S_A)_{A\in U}~\middle|~S_A\subseteq W\backslash A\land\exists w\in W\backslash(\bigcup U):w\not\in\vcenter{\hbox{$\bigcup\limits_{A\in U}$}}S_{A}\right\}\right|\right)\\={}...?$

Evaluating the above expressions demands to iterate all the numbers in sets in sets, compare them to others, etc., which is slow and complicated. Is there a better way, e.g. which eliminates the set between $|\cdot|$?

For example, for $n=3$ and $U=\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$, we have $W\backslash(\bigcup U)=\{0,1,2\}\backslash\{0,1\}=\{2\}$ and
$\begin{array}{lcccc}
\left\{(S_{A})_{A\,\in\,U}\middle|S_A\,\subseteq W\backslash A\right\}=\{&
\color{blue}{(\emptyset,\emptyset)},&\color{blue}{(\{1\},\emptyset)},&(\{2\},\emptyset),&(\{1,2\},\emptyset),\\&
\color{blue}{(\emptyset,\{0\})},&\color{blue}{(\{1\},\{0\})},&(\{2\},\{0\}),&(\{1,2\},\{0\}),\\&
(\emptyset,\{2\}),&(\{1\},\{2\}),&(\{2\},\{2\}),&(\{1,2\},\{2\}),\\&
(\emptyset,\{0,2\}),&(\{1\},\{0,2\}),&(\{2\},\{0,2\}),&(\{1,2\},\{0,2\})\},
\end{array}$
where for $\color{blue}{blue}$ marked elements $(S_A)_{A\in U}$ we do not have $\forall w\in W\backslash(\bigcup U):w\in\vcenter{\hbox{$\bigcup\limits_{A\in U}$}}S_{A}$.

Even though the sets are distributed in their size according to lines of pascal's triangle*, this didn't help me so far, since the crucial aspect seems to rely directly on the numbers. Shouldn't there be some properties shared by many such that not every single set and its numbers have to be utilized for calculation?

*e.g. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}2^n-1\\k\end{array}\right)=2^{2^n-1}-1$  (See [W. A. result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B2%5En-1%7D((2%5En-1)ncr%20k)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can further simplify the expression to

$\vcenter{\hbox{$\sum\limits_{U\in2^{2^{\mathbb{N}_{<n}}\backslash\{\emptyset\}}\backslash\{\emptyset\}}$}}\left(2^{\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$\sum\limits_{A\in U}$}}\left(n-|A|\right)\right)}-s(n\,{-}\,|\bigcup U|)\right)$, for $s(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}l@{}}0 & ,\text{ if }x=0\\
\frac{(2^{|U|}-1)s(x-1)+2^{\left(\vcenter{\hbox{$\sum\limits_{w\in\mathbb{N}_{<n}}$}}\left|\left\{A\in U\middle|w\not\in A\right\}\right|\right)}}{2^{|U|}}&,\text{ if }x>0\end{array}\right.$

of which $s(x)$ can be efficiently computed using recursion.